# Position a block element in the bottom-right of a fieldset

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, alignment

I have several Razor pages in an MVC4 project that follow a general layout that can be viewed [here](http://sylvandaletech.com/BottomRight.html).  Each page will have a `fieldset`, and most will have either a Save or Next or whatever kind of button.  What I'd really like and can't figure out is how to get the Save/Next/Whatever button to always position in the lower-right corner of the `fieldset`.  I've attempted solutions from [a couple of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118513/how-do-i-align-a-div-at-the-bottom-right-corner-of-a-web-page-even-if-the-conten) other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css), but sadly none seem to apply to this situation.  Is this even possible?

Here's the [stylesheet](http://sylvandaletech.com/BottomRight.css).

Comment: Very nice question & answer, but the general layout is no longer working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342144/how-to-make-fieldset-postion-fixed-in-asp-net-based-on-the-visibility

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33342144/4323579 plz help me here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the fieldset in `position:relative` and put the button in `Position:Aboslute` with `bottom:0` and `right:0`, this should work for one button, to place the others, do the same thing but change the right value to the combine width of the other buttons.

Example:

```
.lower-right-button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
<fieldset style="position: relative">
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="lower-right-button">
<input type="submit" value="New" class="lower-right-button" style="right: 110 px">
</fieldset>
```

EDIT: The bottom and right attributes align the bottom and right edge of the element with the bottom and right edge of its container. In that case, `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` will place it at 0 pixel from the bottom-right corner, you might want to put something else like `bottom: 5px` `right:5px`

EDIT AGAIN: Fixed, initial proposition didn't work, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqHjz/2/)

EDIT ONCE AGAIN: With Romias proposition, put the button in a div and position the div at bottom right instead, here's the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqHjz/3/)

Comment: The best is putting the inputs in a div... to position the whole container.

Comment: @Romias You are right, it would actually be better to put the div in `position: absolute` with `bottom:0` and `right:0` and place the buttons inside this div where you can position them however you like.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thanks for the JSFiddles, helped a ton.

Answer (score 6):

**Relative first, then absolute.**

It's quite simple really. The first step is to **set the parent container's position property to *relative*** as follows:

```
<fieldset style="position: relative;">
    ...
</fieldset>
```

This will **set the boundaries** for your next element to be positioned, only this time, using *absolute* positioning.

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

Putting the two together:

```
<fieldset style="position: relative;">

    ...

    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

After this, you can add some margin to this *div* tag (or pull away from the bottom right corner a little) to add some padding, throw in some styles, etc.

Comment: Pretty much what I said except you got it on first try instead of 3 edit later XD

Answer (score 0):

use following CSS for buttons (please adjust margins)

```
position: relative;
margin-top: 45%;
margin-left: 90%;
```