# Make footer stick to bottom of page correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my footer (just a div with a line of text in it) be at the bottom of the screen if the content doesn't go all the way to the bottom, or be at the bottom of the content if the content requires scroll bars.  If the content doesn't require scroll bars, it works perfectly, but when the content is too long, the footer is still in the same spot, sitting right on top of the content.

My basic div structure is:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

My corresponding CSS (stripped down somewhat):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 674px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#body {
    width: 616px;
    padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 644px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This question does not have a reliable answer in the link provided. The accepted answer should be the one provided by Vinicius José Latorre in this question since it is very clear and it works.

Comment: maybe the problem is with the html or body tag. this link helped me : https://makandracards.com/makandra/39473-stretching-an-html-page-to-full-height

Answer (score 248):

The simplest solution is to use `min-height` on the `<html>` tag and position the `<footer>` with `position:absolute;`

**Demo**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/h9mHc/) and SO snippet:

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    /* bottom = footer height */
    padding: 25px;
}

footer {
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <!-- or <div class="container">, etc. -->
    <h1>James Dean CSS Sticky Footer</h1>
    <p>Blah blah blah blah</p>
    <p>More blah blah blah</p>
</article>
<footer>
    <h1>Footer Content</h1>
</footer>
```

Comment: I also liked it- thanks. However, one question: why the "overflow: hidden;"?

Comment: This is a pretty sweet solution. Only drawback is position absolute of footer height... :/. Still I used your solution :)

Comment: For future reference: this wasn't working for me at first because I had explicitly set `html { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: Overflow: hidden is needed, because on narrower viewport footer content could overflow, which will look bad, since Vinicius proposes we set a fixed height of the footer matching body bottom margin. For adaptive layouts we can do without overflow:hidden, compensating with media queries and sizing footer content appropriately instead. Or even adjusting body margin in tandem with footer height to match footer content, for that matter.

Comment: This answer is nice, but it is so uncool to plagerize someone else, line for line, without even giving credit. -1 because of that. http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

Comment: setting absolute for footer is horrible since it covers other static elements on a short page.

Comment: What if my footer size varies based on display size and other factors? I can't use `margin: 0 0 100px;` in that case.. great solution otherwise.

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan maybe you could use some javascript to adjust the body margin, but I didn't test this idea.

Comment: Other comments pointed out the disadvantages of having a fixed footer height. The modern (and arguably more elegant) way is to use flex: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: This works on big screens, but on small screens it stays in its position when I scroll down

Comment: Not bad, but the footer covers the body content.

Answer (score 27):

Why not using: `{ position: fixed; bottom: 0 }` ?

Comment: Because the footer will cover your body content.

Comment: -1 coz then your footer will follow you as you scroll

Comment: how about `position: static`? It works better for me!

Comment: `position: static` is the default positioning of everything - setting that won't do anything to keep your footer at the bottom of the viewport when the content isn't tall enough.

Comment: I think {position: absolute; bottom:0} should do.

Answer (score 19):

**A simple solution that i use, works from IE8+**

Give min-height:100% on html so that if content is less then still page takes full view-port height and footer sticks at bottom of page. When content increases the footer shifts down with content and keep sticking to bottom.

JS fiddle working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3L3h64qo/2/

### Css

```
html{
  position:relative; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
/*Normalize html and body elements,this style is just good to have*/
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.pageContentWrapper{
  margin-bottom:100px;/* Height of footer*/
} 
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

### Html

```
   <html>
    <body>
        <div class="pageContentWrapper">
            <!-- All the page content goes here-->
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this one. It will fix it.

```
#ibox_footer {
    padding-top: 3px; 
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it won't if the containing element ends before the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 4):

Use min-height as some pixel value, instead of `%`.
Like:

```
min-height:620px;
height:auto;
```

and footer as:

```
.footer {
    height:70px;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do it using jQuery put inside code on the `<head></head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var docHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;  
    if (footerTop < docHeight) {
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', 10 + (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It would be hard to manage and understand quickly, neater is a pure css implementation.

Comment: Not so long ago I was doing something similar, but the footer's height was being retrieved differently depending on browser, or even between page refreshes. Looked weird. Although it somewhat works, I advise against this method. I was retrieving outerHeight though.

Comment: @landed the problem with a pure CSS solution is either a `fixed height` or a fixed height and `overflow hidden`.  Anyone using a CMS would struggle and fixed heights in responsive days are not cool.

Comment: @eoin I would agree with you that fixed height is not great for those reasons. But I would prefer a css only solution in a perfect world (or later CSS spec). I want to see zero style or layout created by js ideally.

Comment: For sure, it's not a perfect world, but it's getting there.  Even using HTML in ::after is not a viable solution (and never will be)

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer {
    height: 155px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest hack is to set a `min-height` to your page container at 400px assuming your footer come at the end. you dont even have to put css for the footer or just a `width:100%` assuming your footer is direct child of your `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

The model being shared here is very similar to Ryan Fait's StickyFooter 
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer

Just one div is missing so far in this discussion (the model proposed here by Kenneth Palanganas worked fine for local Win81 design for about 48 hours and then in ie/chrome collapsed for unknown reason). Ryan's "push" div will satisfy some reluctant browsers. Note that px is usual, however, for liquid layout consistency, em may be preferred.

```
* { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
.wrapper { height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -1em; min-height: 100%; }
.footer, .push { height: 1em; }

<div class="wrapper"><p>Your website content here.</p>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"><p>This is a footer</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share how I solved mine using Javascript function that is called on page load. This solution positions the footer at the bottom of the screen when the height of the page content is less than the height of the screen.

```js
function fix_layout(){
  //increase content div length by uncommenting below line
  //expandContent();
  
    var wraph = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetHeight;
    if(wraph<window.innerHeight){ //if content is less than screenheight
        var headh   = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
        var conth   = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
        var footh   = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
        //var foottop = window.innerHeight - (headh + conth + footh);
        var foottop = window.innerHeight - (footh);
        $("#footer").css({top:foottop+'px'});
    }
}

function expandContent(){
  $('#content').append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at ante. Mauris eleifend, quam a vulputate dictum, massa quam dapibus leo, eget vulputate orci purus ut lorem. In fringilla mi in ligula. Pellentesque aliquam quam vel dolor. Nunc adipiscing. Sed quam odio, tempus ac, aliquam molestie, varius ac, tellus. Vestibulum ut nulla aliquam risus rutrum interdum. Pellentesque lorem. Curabitur sit amet erat quis risus feugiat viverra. Pellentesque augue justo, sagittis et, lacinia at, venenatis non, arcu. Nunc nec libero. In cursus dictum risus. Etiam tristique nisl a nulla. Ut a orci. Curabitur dolor nunc, egestas at, accumsan at, malesuada nec, magna.</p>'+

'<p>Nulla facilisi. Nunc volutpat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut sit amet orci vel mauris blandit vehicula. Nullam quis enim. Integer dignissim viverra velit. Curabitur in odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut consequat, tellus eu volutpat varius, justo orci elementum dolor, sed imperdiet nulla tellus ut diam. Vestibulum ipsum ante, malesuada quis, tempus ac, placerat sit amet, elit.</p>'+

'<p>Sed eget turpis a pede tempor malesuada. Vivamus quis mi at leo pulvinar hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque aliquet lacus vitae pede. Nullam mollis dolor ac nisi. Phasellus sit amet urna. Praesent pellentesque sapien sed lacus. Donec lacinia odio in odio. In sit amet elit. Maecenas gravida interdum urna. Integer pretium, arcu vitae imperdiet facilisis, elit tellus tempor nisi, vel feugiat ante velit sit amet mauris. Vivamus arcu. Integer pharetra magna ac lacus. Aliquam vitae sapien in nibh vehicula auctor. Suspendisse leo mauris, pulvinar sed, tempor et, consequat ac, lacus. Proin velit. Nulla semper lobortis mauris. Duis urna erat, ornare et, imperdiet eu, suscipit sit amet, massa. Nulla nulla nisi, pellentesque at, egestas quis, fringilla eu, diam.</p>'+

'<p>Donec semper, sem nec tristique tempus, justo neque commodo nisl, ut gravida sem tellus suscipit nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut tincidunt pretium elit. Aliquam pulvinar. Nulla cursus. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam condimentum hendrerit felis. Duis iaculis aliquam enim. Donec dignissim augue vitae orci. Curabitur luctus felis a metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In varius neque at enim. Suspendisse massa nulla, viverra in, bibendum vitae, tempor quis, lorem.</p>'+

'<p>Donec dapibus orci sit amet elit. Maecenas rutrum ultrices lectus. Aliquam suscipit, lacus a iaculis adipiscing, eros orci pellentesque nisl, non pharetra dolor urna nec dolor. Integer cursus dolor vel magna. Integer ultrices feugiat sem. Proin nec nibh. Duis eu dui quis nunc sagittis lobortis. Fusce pharetra, enim ut sodales luctus, lectus arcu rhoncus purus, in fringilla augue elit vel lacus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce iaculis elit id tellus. Ut accumsan malesuada turpis. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum lacus augue, lobortis mattis, laoreet in, varius at, nisi. Nunc gravida. Phasellus faucibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempor lacus eget lectus. Praesent fringilla augue fringilla dui.</p>');
}
```

```css
/*sample CSS*/
body{ background: black; margin: 0; }
#header{ background: grey; }
#content{background: yellow; }
#footer{ background: red; position: absolute; }

#header, #content, #footer{ display: inline-block; width: 100vw; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="fix_layout()">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                [some header elements here]
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="container">
              [some content elements here]
              
              
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="footer">
                [some footer elements here]
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Hope that helps.