# How to keep footer at bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
 * {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 html {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 body {
     line-height: 1;
     margin: 0px;
     padding:0px;
     background:url("../images/22.jpg") scroll center top #16202C;
     /*  box-shadow: 0 0 225px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 225px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:  0 0 225px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) inset;
-o-box-shadow:  0 0 225px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) inset; */
     color: #464646;
     font: 13px/17px arial, sans-serif;
     min-width: 1300px;
 }
 #wrapper {
     margin: 0px;
 }
 #header {
     height: 40px;
     width: 100%;
 }
 #bodyWrapper {
     width: 980px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000 outset;
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0px 2px #000 outset;
     box-shadow: 20px 0px 2px #000 outset;
 }
 #bodyDiv {
     min-height: 550px;
     height: 100%;
     background:#fff;
     padding:20px 10px;
 }
 #footer {
     background: url("../images/footer_back.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
     height: 100px;
     margin-top: -50px;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="topHeaderBar"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="bodyWrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
            <div id="bodyDiv" style="position: relative;">body content</div>
            <div id="footer">
                <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Please help me out, I'm not able to adjust footer at bottom of page
when body contents are less footer will be shifted upwards and min-height:550px in #bodyDiv creates problem in different screen resolutions

Comment: Best possible solution http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: check sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Ryan fait's sticky footer is by far the best way of doing it.

Comment: why dont you use `position:fixed` for the footer to keep it at the bottom???

Comment: If you use `position: fixed` and then scroll down, the footer stays where it was so you always have a footer int he middle of your screen if you scroll down.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 #footer {
     background: url("../images/footer_back.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
     height: 100px;
     margin-top: -50px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom:0;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
 }
```

Comment: footer will be set at bottom but body content height is not 100%

Comment: make height of `wrapper` and `bodyWrapper` 100% (`height:100%;`)

Comment: dude not working. Content height is still not 100%

Comment: I found this http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
 <div id="topHeaderBar"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="bodyWrapper">
                <div id="header">
                    <jsp:include page="menu.jsp"></jsp:include>
                </div>
                <div id="bodyDiv" style="position: relative;">body content</div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS :

```
 html,body{
        height: 100%
    }

    #header{
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #holder {
        min-height: 100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    #body {
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }

    #footer{
        background-color: lime;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Divya i don't want sticky footer, simply want's to set footer at bottom of browser window when contents on page are less. Thank you for your help

Comment: Here is the example what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/  and http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/1/  if you have any question let me know.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I have used the above mentioned html layout and for me it's not possible to change it. Could you please modify my above given code and css, so that it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ELUGc/  use this.

Comment: Use above edited code. its surely working.

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer {
     background: url("../images/footer_back.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
     height: 100px;
     margin-top: -50px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
     clear:both;
 }
```

Comment: sorry, not working properly

Comment: Sorry for making you work Try this it is working at my end. See answer i have modified it.