# How to stick footer always to the bottom of the page if the content is very less?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The footer should remain in the bottom even when i re size the page. In my case footer is overlapping the contents when i re size the height of the page.

```css
 .body{
     background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size:85%;
            height: 100%;
    }

    .container{
     min-height:100%;
     position: relative;
    }
    .formContainer{
     width:30%;
        height: 100px;
     background-color:#fff;
     margin:auto;
            padding-top: 0;
     border-radius:5px;
     box-shadow:5px 5px 55px #9999;
     padding-bottom:60px;
    }
    .footer{
        position:absolute;
     width:100%;
        bottom:0;
     height:60px;
     background-color:#333;
    }
```

```html
<body class="body">
       <header class="header">
     </header>
       <div class="container">
                    <div class="formContainer">
                    </div>
      <footer class="footer">
      </footer>
         </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make footer stick to bottom of page correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly)

Comment: Used to this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

You should move footer tag out of the div

```
<header class="header">
    </header>
    <div class="container">
                <div class="formContainer">
                </div>        
     </div>
    <footer class="footer">
    </footer>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wds3x/)**

---

Add `height:100%` to html and body, then only your container takes height 100% and leave your html code as it is.

```
html, body{
    height:100%
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wds3x/1/)**

P S - I think `.body` in your CSS is a mistake, it should be only `body`

Comment: Problem is when i re size the height of the page and make the window smaller, the footer is overlapping the other contents of the page. I want it to always be on the bottom. It should not Come up with the page . when i re size it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Sticky Footer, there are couple of ways to implement it.

1. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/ (using CSS)
2. http://josephfitzsimmons.com/home/simple-sticky-footer-using-jquery/ (using jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/WPYCJ/

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Thanks

CSS

```
 .body{
    background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:85%;
        height: 100%;
}

.container{
 height:90%;
background-color:#fff;
}
.formContainer{
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
        margin:auto;
        padding-top: 0;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 55px #9999;
    padding-bottom:60px;
}
.footer{
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:5%;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="body">
    <header class="header">
    </header>
    <div class="container">
                <div class="formContainer">
                </div>
             </div>
<footer class="footer">test
        </footer>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem, I used this code :

```
<script>
    var top = $(document).height() - $("footer.main-footer").height() ; 
     $("footer.main-footer").css('top' , top);
</script>
```

Change .main-footer to your footer's class.