# Stick a footer to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

How do I make a footer which will stick to the bottom of the page and that will move with my content? I tried using `position`, but when there was more content than would fit on the screen, the footer stayed at the bottom of the screen, with content overlaying on top of it.

Comment: show fiddle of whatever you have tried

Comment: This is duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly - Did you Google this?

Comment: Why Why Why after so many faq and help topics why come up with an incomplete question . We cannot build an entire page sitting here .

Comment: And why do even answers keep on popping :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method fixed my problem. I think it should fix all the problem related sticky footer. Thank you for all responding to my question.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
footer.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $('#x')[0].scrollHeight < $(window).height() ) {
    $('footer').addClass('bottom');
} else {
    $('footer').removeClass('bottom');
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="x">
<table height="1000" bgcolor="#999999">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

    <footer>
    Lorem Ipsum
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make css class for footer -

```
footer.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Than with jQuery

```
if ( $(document).height() < $(window).height() ) {
    $('footer').addClass('bottom');
} else {
    $('footer').removeClass('bottom');
}
```

So if body is shorter than window, it would add class to make it stick with bottom, but if body is higher, then it would be normal.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using div to make the footer. Have you tried the `z-index` CSS property? A larger `z-index` would cause the element to appear in front.

Just a suggestion to try out.

Answer (score -1):

if you use:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
```

That should do it

And `width:100%;` if you need it.

Comment: But I need the footer which should always stand after the contents. position: fixed footer will be fixed on the page always..

Comment: please read the question complete :" I tried using position. But when the content became larger than the monitor height then the content overwrite on the footer. "