# CSS DIV Navigation & Body to Footer

Tags: html, css, footer, stretch

I've spent countless hours trying to fix my CSS/Divs up and searched online for great help and tutorials. Unforunately, I have given up coming this far in progress in my code.

What I already have is a layout with a header, header bar underneath it, following by a left side navigation pane and the body of the page on the right of it. Furthermore, there's a footer at the end of the page that I want to always touch the bottom of the window and have both the navigation pane and body div to stretch to it.

I kind of got it working... although it's not reaching the bottom of the page entirely. Have a look... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

[image]

Please help!!!

Thank you.

**Code:**

> ```
> <div id="wrapper1">
>   <div id="header1">
>     <p><strong>sdfsdfsdf</strong></p>
>   </div>
>   <header id="navigation1" align="center">
>     header bar here
>   </header>
>   <div id="contentliquid1">
>     <div id="content11">body of the page here</div>
>   </div>
>   <div id="leftcolumn1" valign="top">navigation pane here</div>
>   <div id="footer1" align="center" style="display: table;">
>     <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">asdasdasd</div>
>   </div>    
> </div>
> ```

**CSS:**

> ```
> body,html {
>   background-color: #D5DAE0;
>   background-image: url();
>   background-repeat:no-repeat;
>   background-attachment:scroll;
>   background-position:top;
>   margin: 0px;
>   padding: 0px;
>   height:100%;
> } 
> div {
>   border-width: 1px;
>   border-spacing: 1px;
>   border-style: solid;
>   border-color: #999999;
>   border-collapse: collapse;
>   border-left: 0px;   
>   border-right: 0px;  
> }
> #wrapper1 {
>     width: 100%;
>     min-width: 962px;
>     max-width: 962px;
>     margin: auto;
>     height: 100%;
>     margin-bottom: -30px;
>     position: relative;
> }
> #header1 {
>     float: left;
>     height: 75px;
>     width: 100%;      
>     border: 0px;
>     border-left: 1px solid #999999;
>     border-right: 1px solid #999999;
> }
> #navigation1 {
>     float: left;
>     height: 32px;
>     width: 100%;
>     border: 0px;
>     border-left: 1px solid #999999;
>     border-right: 1px solid #999999;
> }
> #contentliquid1 {
>     float: left;
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 100%;
>     margin-bottom: -30px;
>     position: relative;
>     border-left: 1px solid #999999; 
>     border-right: 1px solid #999999;   
> }
> #content11 {
>     margin-left: 260px;
>     height: 100%;
>     border: 0px;
> }
>
> #leftcolumn1 {
>     float: left;
>     width: 241px;
>     margin-left: -100%;
>     border-left: 0px;
>     border-right: 1px solid; 
>     border-color: #999999;
>     min-height: 100%;
>     margin-bottom: -1px;
>     position: relative;
> }
> #footer1 {
>     height: 30px;
>     width: 100%;
>     clear: both;
>     border: 0px;
>     border-left: 1px solid; 
>     border-top: 1px solid; 
>     border-color: #999999;
>     position: relative;
> }
> ```

Comment: this post has what your looking for a ["sticky footer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly)

Comment: I've tried applying the same code to mine but it doesn't work well with my left navigation panel next to the body. I really don't understand why. :-(

Comment: do you have a wrapper for the content (one that goes around your left navigation bar and the "main" div)? I think if you don't that might be able to get the other code working

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zuGLH/29/ ??

Force the footer to stay at the bottom of the window (not the end of the content):

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

And then I flexed out the two middle columns to fill:

```
.body {
  clear: both;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

**EDIT:** And to make sure the columns fill the available height, first make sure the page does:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And then add to whatever else should fill:

```
.body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In the case of the columns, add the height to their parent container.

Comment: This is excellent but how do I make "sideNav" and "main" both stretch down to the footer with a background color along with that border line in between? Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Rx276/

Comment: You should be aware that this solution is only IE11+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Kaceykaso Yes however the sideNav and main stretch beyond footer and the footer does not remain to the bottom of the window. I was looking forward to seeing both sideNav and main stretch up to the top border of the moving footer.