# Footer is not getting displayed at bottom

Tags: html, css, express, pug

Please find the CSS style of the footer.

```
#footer {

  background-color: #000;

  bottom: 0px;

  color: #fff;

  clear: both;

  text-align: center;

  padding: 5px;

}
```

How to make footer get displayed at bottom of page (web browser)?

Comment: Please try to follow this link,  Hope this will help you out ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly

Comment: please provide live link or dummy where we can see other css too and you can go with bottom:0 and position but depends on structure..so please provide dummy..thnx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#footer {

  background-color: #000;

  bottom: 0px;

  color: #fff;

  clear: both;

  text-align: center;

  padding: 5px;

 position:absolute;

}
```

Hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<div class="footer" id="footer">My Footer</div>
```

## footer

{

```
   clear: both; 
   border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: normal;
   margin: 0;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;
```

}

Try it out here http://jsfiddle.net/RDuWn/