# How to make footer stick to bottom in blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

The footer in the main home page works fine: https://michaelarabic.blogspot.com/

It doesn't work when you're on a Page or a Post.

- Page: https://michaelarabic.blogspot.com/p/home.html
- Post: https://michaelarabic.blogspot.com/2019/03/test-2.html

This is one of the default blogger templates. I tried to figure out what's the `<div>` that is responsible for the footer.
Using ***inspect*** feature in Chrome, I can guess that they are the ones that have those classes: ***footer-outer*** and ***footer-fauxborder-left***.

After figuring out the possible or the potential class names. I used the method in this question: [Make footer stick to bottom of page correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443606/make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page-correctly)

There was some changes in the footer but that's not what I wanted. It became very thin and it doesn't respond to changing the height. I faced some issues while trying different solutions from other websites.

If it's hard or impossible to stick the footer to the bottom. At least, I need a method to hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple,

just fix the

> position of your footer content to fixed

,it will ready your content to fix to a point, now the browser looks for the position where it need to be fixed so just pass

> bottom:0;

now in your case the content is not containing the full width so to recover that we need to provide a

> width to 100%

so your final code looks something like this.

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```