# making a div extend all the way down to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, layout

My website has varaible content length, and this sometime means that the footer does not site at the bottom of the page, is there a way to make the footer fill whatever space is left?

http://www.ibdnetwork.co.uk/members-content/forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at excellent post at CSS-Tricks.Com:

- [A Bulletproof Sticky Footer, Woohoo!](http://css-tricks.com/sticky-footer/)

[See the demo here :)](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: links broken on both demo and the page in the link.

Answer (score 1):

**css**

```
#footer {
  position:fixed !important;
  bottom:0;
}
```

This should do it. You can add a padding on your content wrapper that have the height of your footer + 50px or something like that, for spacing between content and footer. The footer will be on top of your content else.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this problem. One is to have

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

in your CSS. This, however, might create issues on pages that scroll vertically. For complex cases you will have to resort to JavaScript onResize coding.

See if this helps:

[How do I force a DIV block to extend to the bottom of a page even if it has no content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147528/how-to-force-a-div-block-to-extend-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-even-if-it-has-no-con)