# extend div all way down

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force a DIV block to extend to the bottom of a page even if it has no content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147528/how-do-i-force-a-div-block-to-extend-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-even-if-it-has-no-c)

I have a div here that i want to extend all the way to the bottom of the page.

I want to extend bottomHalf all the way down basically no matter the resolution it will just go all the way down.

I put `height: 100%;` in bottomHalf but its not working

```
  <div id="navigation">
 blah blah
  </div>


  <div id="bottomHalf">
EXTEND ALL THE WAY!!!
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 55px;
    background-image:url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#bottomHalf {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4d3c37;
}
```

Here is a jsiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/3J9xd/

Comment: I tried min-height:100%;
height: 100%; in my wrapper and in BottomHalf but it dosent work

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case showing what you have so far?

Comment: Here we go!!! http://jsfiddle.net/3J9xd/

Comment: I want the bottomhalf to extend all the way down to the end of the page no matter the resolution of screen ect

Comment: What should happen when there's too much text inside `#bottomHalf` to fit "on the screen"? Should the page then have a vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/zTWhn/

```
html, body, #wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    position: relative;
}
#navigation {
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#bottomHalf {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4d3c37;
}
```

Comment: this does not work with larger content: http://jsfiddle.net/master1991/c0hdk4re/

Comment: @Ingus: It's not really a case of "does not work", more like "nobody specified what should happen". You can do this, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/754s0vLw/1/. Or are you just trying to make a sticky footer? There's not enough detail in the original question or your comment, to be honest.

Comment: That is true! I have to make left nav bar that all the time  need to be  till end of the page. I have dynamic container next to nav container.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add

html, body{height:100%;}

And put the height of your div to 100%

Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/3J9xd/1/

EDIT:

Is it better like this : http://jsfiddle.net/3J9xd/5/

Comment: Now it jsut goes like 200000 pixels more than the page

Comment: are you sure, on my side i've got 55px ... but i'm looking for another solution

Answer (score 0):

height: 100%; does work. you are not seeing it extend due to the height of your wrapper class. If you set the height on your wrapper class to a fixed height you will see the bottomHalf div extend.

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height:500px;
}

#bottomHalf {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4d3c37;
}
```