# CSS/HTML to extent image width to the sides

Tags: html, css

I have been looking everywhere for an answer but cannot find it anywhere...

What i want to do is:
   - Extent all the images on my website to the sides of the screen (ie: get rid of the margins)

I have put the below code in CSS:

```
#bg {
position: fixed; 
top: -50%; 
left: -50%; 
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
z-index: -100;
```

And added the below on the HTML side:

```
<div id="bg">
 <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

However this code is to fit a background image to fit the whole screen..

I am a novice at coding, and would much appreciate your help.

Fabien

Comment: Why not use `background-image:url('image.png');`?

Comment: You need to remove the default margins/padding that the browser stylesheet sets. Take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/reset-all-margins-padding/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force a DIV block to extend to the bottom of a page even if it has no content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147528/how-do-i-force-a-div-block-to-extend-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-even-if-it-has-no-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you want the image to fit the full screen.
There is no need to use fixed positioning.

```
*{
margin:0;padding:0;
}

.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.container img{
width:100%;
height:100;
}
```

1. Just set the width of the container in which the image is contained to a width and height of 100%;
2. Remove the default padding provided by the browser

[DEMO PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/rb1cK4gyl4A9o1IqAPiS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

1. fixed position will make the image scroll when you scroll down the page.
   [just pointing it out]
2. what are you asking? are you asking how to make the picture fit the entire background?