# CSS: Have content take up remaining height and its children share the same height equally

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-lamport-v9bsnn?file=/index.html:0-707) is a link to a CodeSandbox with the code below.

There is a div with a class of `content` that I want to take up the remaining height and have the children share the rest of the height (2 children => both take half; 3 children => each takes a third etc.), while taking up the full width.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I tried both `grid` and `flex` approaches, but wasn't able to make either work.

How would you achieve this layout?

The code:

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" class="app">
      <h1 class="sr-only">My Title</h1>
      <nav class="nav">
        <li>some</li>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>items</li>
      </nav>

      <header>
        <h2>
          Where do you want to go?
        </h2>
      </header>

      <!-- Content should take all of the remaining available height -->
      <div class="content">
        <!-- Link 1, 2, and 3 should take a third of content's height each and take up the full width -->
        <a>Link 1</a>
        <a>Link 2</a>
        <a>Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js`:

```js
import "./styles.css";
```

`styles.css`:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.app {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: `CSS-Grid` with a `min-height` and `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` should solve your issue.

Comment: I have adapted https://stackoverflow.com/a/23986464/3807365 and just added 33% height to the remaining items. https://jsfiddle.net/itgoldman/znxy2ue5/2/ but I didn't narrow it down to minimal css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `flex`:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #00fa
}

.app,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: #fe0;
}

.content > a {
  flex: 1;
  border:solid 1px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="app">
  <nav class="nav">
    <li>some</li>
    <li>nav</li>
    <li>items</li>
  </nav>

  <header>
    <h2>
      Where do you want to go?
    </h2>
  </header>

  <!-- Content should take all of the remaining available height -->
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Link 1, 2, and 3 should take a third of content's height each and take up the full width -->
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <a>Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```